# Pairwise distances between n points on a unit circle

Tags: optimization, geometry

Consider $n $ points on the circumference of a unit circle.What configuration of them will maximise the total pairwise distance between them.To me it seems the points should be equally spaced .The total pairwise  distance is given by :\begin{equation*}
D = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \sqrt{2 - 2\cos(\theta_j - \theta_k)}
\end{equation*} where the angles are between 0 and $2\pi.$ If my instinct is right then all agles are equal.But proving that using calculus seems almost impossible for large n.Can there be some argument using some simple geomtric or symmetry argument or any other approach by passing messy  calculus? I would be obliged for any help/ hints in this regard

Comment: Just checking: is the distance between two points measured through the interior of the disk or around the circumference of the circle?  Your radical sign suggests through the interior

Comment: Just the straight distance between them

Comment: I think the distance between two points is the greatest when the circular sector form by them is also the greatest. This make think of the polygon approximation of a circle which is: a line, a triangle, a square...

Answer (score 2):

This sketch argues, without calculus, that OP's instinct is correct.

The number of distinct pairwise distances in an $n$-gon is $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$, e.g. $3$, $6$, $10$, $15$... for $n=3$, $4$, $5$, $6$....
[image: max distance between points in n-gon]
**I.** Consider regular pentagon $ABCDE$. The distances are $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $AE$, $BC$, $BD$, $BE$, $CD$, $CE$, $DE$: $4+3+2+1=10$. Suppose we break the regularity by moving point $A$ to some position $F$, between $A$ and $E$.

Granting that the perimeter of an isosceles triangle is greater than that of any other triangle with equal base and vertex angle, then$$AB+AE>FB+FE$$For the same reason$$AC+AD>FC+FD$$Therefore$$AB+AC+AD+AE>FB+FC+FD+FE$$The sum of distances, then, between any vertex of a pentagon and the other vertices is greater if the pentagon is regular than if the pentagon is not regular. The same argument will apply to all odd $n$-gons.

**II.** If $n$ is even, as in the next figure, then again$$GH+GM>NH+NM$$likewise$$GJ+GL>NJ+NL$$and lastly, since $GK$ is a diameter$$GK>NK$$
[image: even n-gon]
Therefore$$GH+GJ+GK+GL+GM>NH+NJ+NK+NL+NM$$The sum of distances between any vertex of an even $n$-gon and the remaining vertices is greater if the even $n$-gon is regular than if it is not regular.

**Addendum**:

**III**. Since, as @Jarle Tufto comments, the above deals only with a certain class of irregular $n$-gon, namely those with just one vertex displaced on the circle, the following attempts to prove the general case for $n=4$.

Let $ABCD$ be any irregular cyclic quadrilateral with diagonals $AC$, $BD$. To one of the diagonals, say $BD$, draw perpendicular bisector $EF$, and join $EB$, $BF$, $FD$, $DE$, forming kite $EBFD$ about diameter $EF$.
[image: general case, n=4]
Since triangle $EBD$ is isosceles, then$$EB+ED>AB+AD$$and since triangle $FBD$ is isosceles, then$$FB+FD>CB+CD$$Therefore, the sides of the kite sum to more than the sides of $ABCD$.

Now complete square $EHFG$ about diameter $EF$, in which therefore$$GE+GF>DE+DF$$and$$HE+HF>BE+BF$$Therefore, the sides of square $EHFG$ sum to more than the sides of kite $EDFB$, which sum to more than the sides of quadrilateral $ABCD$.

Finally, diagonals$$EF+GH\ge AC+DB$$Therefore, the sum of the six pairwise distances between the vertices of a cyclic quadrilateral is greatest for a square.

Question: Is there a way to extend this strategy to other even $n$-gons, or perhaps  to cases where $n=2^{2m}$? Or does this $4$-sided kite fly only once?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I wa trying to do the same but somehow  got lost while comparing the new distances with old distances.You did well to separate the even and odd cases

Comment: This is really elegant

Comment: Your argument only considers irregular polygons obtained by moving a single point of a regular polygon at a time.  So you haven't ruled out that more irregular polygons exist for which the sum of the distances is greater.

Comment: @Jarle Tufto, I agree, the sketch is incomplete so far.